# Replacing line contains NULL byte with '0' value

Tags: python

[Columns with Null Byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMYsH.png)How can I replace the NULL byte with '0' value after opening up csv file?

My code is as follow but it doesn't work:

```
 try:
                # open source file
                with open (dataFile,'r')as csvfile: 
                    
                    sourceDF = csv.reader(csvfile)
                
                    replaced = [sourceDF.replace(b'\0',b'0') for sourceDF in replaced]
                    print(replaced)
                    
                    first_line = True
                    selHeaders = []
                
                    
                    # read each row in source file
                    for dataRow in sourceDF:      
                    
                        # check if first line of file
                        if first_line == True:
                            first_line = False
                            first_row = dataRow
                            
                            # check if first file in compile list
                            if first_run == 0:
                                result.append(list())
```

Attached hyper link for the csv files for your reference:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bPbE3hnO7ZAQEVTQ4prHUkEkqlDa7QTi?usp=share_link

Best regards

Tried following code but doesn't work

```
replaced = [sourceDF.replace(b'\0',b'0') for sourceDF in replaced]

print(replaced)
```

Comment: Python is an indentation aware language. Please make sure that the indentation of the code you post here matches the one you have.

Comment: What is the difference between "Tried following code" compared to your original code?

Comment: Maybe you want to think about what `replaced` is at the time you do `[... for ... in replaced]`

Comment: "It doesn't work" can be multiple things. What does it do when "it doesn't work"? What is the actual output and what is the expected output?

Comment: `replaced = [sourceDF.replace(b'\0',b'0') for sourceDF in replaced]` isn't going to work. You're trying to create a new list `replaced` by iterating over a not-yet existing list `replaced`, and you're overwriting the CSV reader `sourceDF` you just created a line previously by using it as the iterator variable.

Comment: If you are on a Linux system, it would be much smarter to fix these files BEFORE you suck them into Python.  `tr "\000" 0 < DAQ_LOG_20221109_000000.csv > fix.csv` fixes all of these.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in these two lines:

```py
sourceDF = csv.reader(csvfile)
replaced = [sourceDF.replace(b'\0',b'0') for sourceDF in replaced]
```

The first line reads data from the CSV file. `replaced` is `None` at this time.

The second line now tries to iterate over `replaced`, which is `None` - which doesn't work. But even if it would work, it would immediately replace `sourceDF` with the things it iterates over, thus making the CSV data disappear.

I'm not sure whether replacing `\0` by `0` is a good idea. In my 25 years of coding, I never replaced `\0` by a visible character. I only replaced it by nothing, space or `\n`. But I can't really judge in your case, because I don't understand what kind of data you have and what the numbers mean.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your explanation. Then how can I edit the code to overcome the null byte issue? Because i was trying to append the data subsequently and it doesn't work when there is null byte detected in the csv files. Attached screenshot of how the null byte looks like(when viewing using notepad++) in the post for your reference.

Comment: @Zhang: I know how a NUL byte looks like in Notepad++. I can't tell you how to deal with it, because I don't know what the data in column 3283 means. Is it a temperature? Is it a velocity? Is it a math grade? Is it a countdown for a bomb? I really don't know. In some cases, it may be good to replace it with 0. In other cases you have `3\0` which becomes `30` after replacement. Is it good to have a value of 30 in column 223?

Comment: You have 7324 columns and probably you need to understand all of them in order to clen up the data before you process it. And it would probably be a good question why the data is in such a bad shape in the first place. So that you at least get better data in the future

Comment: Hi Thomas, all the null byte columns are referring to a PLC coil signal which can be either 1 or 0 only.

Comment: Well, as I said: you have data like `3\0` in the column named `from_block_No_3n4_CHAR`, where your definition of a coil does not match.

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes. For cases like 3\0 can become 30 after replacement is okay. I will filter away the null byte columns in the subsequent steps after appending of data. I am fine with any data to be replaced for the null byte columns.

Comment: Okay, then do it.

Comment: Hi Thomas, but my current code does not work and I'm not sure if I am coding in the correct way for the replace function.